# k8s ingress v1.22 wildcard path issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, kong, kong-ingress

i have some problem with wildcard path when i convert apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 because of version update k8s v1.22

The wildcard path in the back doesn't matter
i have a problem changing the wildcard path between like this abcd/*/bcde
this is my example code

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-api-sample
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: my-api-sample
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: "200-204"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /transactions/example/status
        backend:
          serviceName: my-example
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /orders/*/example
        backend:
          serviceName: my-example
          servicePort: 80
```

second path /orders/*/example k8s v1.22
i tried to use regex for that

but it doesn't support wildcard for it
prefix, exact path shouldn't contain wildcards: /orders/.*/example
how can i convert to that wildcard path?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use regex on `Path` for AWS ALB. (nginx-ingress support it).
But you can do the same behavior with ALB Listener conditions. ([Path condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions)).

How to use Path condition on ingress? Visit [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/ingress/annotations/#:%7E:text=%3A%20use%2Dannotation-,alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.%24%7Bconditions%2Dname%7D,-Provides%20a%20method)

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-path1: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"Host is www.example.com OR anno.example.com"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path1: >
      [{"field":"host-header","hostHeaderConfig":{"values":["anno.example.com"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-path2: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"Path is /path2 OR /anno/path2"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path2: >
      [{"field":"path-pattern","pathPatternConfig":{"values":["/anno/path2"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-path3: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"Http header HeaderName is HeaderValue1 OR HeaderValue2"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path3: >
      [{"field":"http-header","httpHeaderConfig":{"httpHeaderName": "HeaderName", "values":["HeaderValue1", "HeaderValue2"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-path4: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"Http request method is GET OR HEAD"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path4: >
      [{"field":"http-request-method","httpRequestMethodConfig":{"Values":["GET", "HEAD"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-path5: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"Query string is paramA:valueA1 OR paramA:valueA2"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path5: >
      [{"field":"query-string","queryStringConfig":{"values":[{"key":"paramA","value":"valueA1"},{"key":"paramA","value":"valueA2"}]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-path6: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"Source IP is 192.168.0.0/16 OR 172.16.0.0/16"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path6: >
      [{"field":"source-ip","sourceIpConfig":{"values":["192.168.0.0/16", "172.16.0.0/16"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.rule-path7: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"multiple conditions applies"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.rule-path7: >
      [{"field":"http-header","httpHeaderConfig":{"httpHeaderName": "HeaderName", "values":["HeaderValue"]}},{"field":"query-string","queryStringConfig":{"values":[{"key":"paramA","value":"valueA"}]}},{"field":"query-string","queryStringConfig":{"values":[{"key":"paramB","value":"valueB"}]}}]
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /path1
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: rule-path1
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /path2
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: rule-path2
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /path3
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: rule-path3
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /path4
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: rule-path4
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /path5
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: rule-path5
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /path6
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: rule-path6
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
          - path: /path7
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: rule-path7
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
```